# Qt- Where can I find the list of fonts I can use?

Tags: c++, qt

When setting a font in a `Qt` application, where can I find the list of fonts I can choose from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [`QFontDatabase`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfontdatabase.html) class to get information about available fonts in the underlying window system.

Comment: more specifically, the `QFontDatabase::families()` method